# Laravel 5: edit record by using popup edit form

Tags: forms, laravel, popup

I have a list of product with "edit" link next to each items. After logging in, I would like to edit each product by clicking on the "edit" link to them. Then, I would like the edit form popup for editing and submitting, rather than redirecting to www.example.com/product/12/edit page. When submitting, I would like to perform Ajax submission so on and so forth. FYI. I am using Bootstrap with Laravel 5.

Please advise me to achieve this popup edit form.

Thanks,
Naren

Comment: You can use Modal in bootstrap. Populate it with data. When click on edit link => fire JS to open Modal, then use Ajax to send request

Comment: i have used http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/ pretty good library (if you want to use the frame and got a lot of data.

Comment: Hello KmasterYC, could you give me a sample laravel coding, which includes select dropdown?